# Sample cairo applications to test cairo-gles backend in 1.12.14

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, cairo

I was able to successfully port, cross compile and run the cairo gears
application in gles backend, on my embedded system target.
http://people.linaro.org/~afrantzis/cairogears-0~git20100719.2b01100+gles2.tar.gz
The ported samples trap, comp, text and shadow run well in cairo1.12.3
and  1.12.4.
But I face problem in running the same in 1.12.14.
I could not run the texture related samples like comp, text, shadow.
Trap plays well but the gradient could not be displayed in the gradient sample.
I use gles backend and converting all image surfaces I load from png
file to gl surface.
Let me know if there is something that should be done for the
texture+gradient samples to work in 1.12.14.

thanks
Sundara raghavan

Comment: Link has linkrotted.   But it appears the code can still be obtained from https://launchpad.net/~afrantzis/+archive/ubuntu/cairo-gles2

Answer (score 2):

The problem was because of the need to convert the GL_BGRA,the internal image format of cairo , to GL_RGBA for loading in to GL textures (which were GL_RGBA by default). I solved it by applying an existing patch which uses BGRA GL texture and hence avoids conversion. This was possible because my hardware is capable of both  reading as well as creating bgra textures.

The Patch was found here:
http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/cairo/2013-February/024038.html